# Trouble understanding flask logic

Tags: python, flask, web

I want develop a web application with flask so I started learning it.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"
```

In this piece of code what exactly is the `@app.route("/")` for?

In my app I have made a form which gets data like name, class and section and stores it in a sql database. Here is the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, flash, redirect
import sqlite3
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('Main.html')


@app.route('/addrec',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def addrec():
   if request.method == 'POST':
  
     std = request.form['class']
     section = request.form['Section'].lower()
     Alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
     if section not in Alphabet:
         return render_template("NoSuchSection.html")
```

In this I can observe that above the addrec() there is `@app.route('/addrec',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])`.

So what is exactly `@app.route()` and what are all its uses in flask ?

(I want to understand its uses because after that only I can use it efficiently in my projects)

I have seen similar questions but I cannot understand them

Comment: You should have done the [Quickstart](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/): *"We then use the route() decorator to tell Flask what URL should trigger our function."*

Comment: Please tell me if there are any errors in the question or you have trouble understanding it. I am new to this community.

Comment: Thank you @KlausD. I will read the flask documentation to understand it.

Comment: What sort of URL is "/" ?

Comment: `/` is for home page , by default. When you will run your flask application and hit the url in browser, it would land you on home page url , that `/` route

Comment: Well I do not know python fully so the documentation was too tough for me to understand. That is why I asked this question in this website. (I did not expect to get an answer here so soon) Thanks for you time.

Comment: You can see my answer below, it would help you to get a basic understanding of that and can run as well

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am able to understand it very well.

Comment: Happy learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`route()` is a decorator in flask which tells about the path/url in your application. Whatever path you want to have in your application, you have to put that in `route()`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home_page():
    return 'hompage'


@app.route('/user')
def user():
    return 'user_page'


@app.route('/shopping')
def shopping():
    return 'shopping'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

This is a very basic example. Here, there are three different path/url in your application as `/user`, `/shopping` and `/` means home page.
When you will run your application, your sever would provide you some url where this flask application would be serving something like `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/`

so when you hit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/`  it will land you on very home page due to `/` path and you would see `homepage` message in your browser.

similarly when you hit `http://127.0.0.1:5000/users` , you would be seeing `user_page` as message in your browser as `/user` path was hitted

Answer (score 1):

They are called decorators. It special functionality. In Flask, app.route() is what you want your URL to be.

For example:

```
@app.route(‘/hello’)
```

Would be for http://yourdomain.com/hello or http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello Whatever website you are running the server on.

You can learn more about decorators here: https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/